# Javascript: How to get a translated word out of the field of a Google Translate page?

Tags: javascript, firefox

In the [**Google Translate page**](https://translate.google.com.tw/?hl=en&tab=wT#en/hi/milk) I type in the word "milk" in English, and it gets instantly translated into Hindi:[image].

Now I need to somehow get that Hindi word out and place it into the clipboard.

I wonder how can I do it in Javascript?

I am using FireFox

Comment: Have you actually tried anything?

Comment: I suggest to use google translate api in your application https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/using_rest

Comment: @Nit - "Have you actually tried anything?" - No, I haven't. I don't even know what to start here with.

Comment: @chf - "I suggest to use google translate api in your application" - Thank you for this link, but it states there, that the google translate api is a paid service. I think I better try a free way - I am not translating a sentence, but only one separate word, and I can still do it manually absolutely free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although as already mentioned in the comments it is preferable to use [the Google Translate API](https://developers.google.com/translate/), it is still possible to do what you are asking via JavaScript.

First, navigate to the [Google Translate page](https://translate.google.com.tw/?hl=en&tab=wT#en/hi/milk) and open a web console; the console can be opened in FireFox by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, or by going to the tools menu and selecting *Developer > Web Console*).

Then type the following command:

```
document.querySelector('#result_box').textContent
```

That is how you retrieve the value. As for the second step, support for copying data to the cilpboard in JavaScript, is, well, an absolute mess: [*How to copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/400212/617937)

I'm a bit out of the loop with new features in JavaScript and HTML, so they may have added proper cross-browser clipboard support in the latest versions, however, the top answer in that question actually works quite well. Here it is applied to our existing code:

```
var translatedText = document.querySelector('#result_box').textContent;
window.prompt("Press CTRL+C to copy the translated text to the clipboard, then ENTER to close the dialog", translatedText);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have a small follow-up question: How did you find out that the parameter should be exactly "#result_box"? Is it like you have inspected the HTML page and somehow got that info from the page? Never could've even imagined that saving values into clipboard was so hard in Javascript. I wonder if at least outputting into a file on the computer is possible. Well, this is, of course, a separate question - I have just asked it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24690384/no-saving-or-outputting-is-possible-in-javascript   Thanks again for this answer.

Comment: @brilliant I right-clicked the text box, chose _Inspect Element_, and then navigated around until I found what I was looking for: `<span id="result_box" class="short_text" lang="hi">`

Comment: @brilliant Of course, one could also search by just digging through the HTML source, but FireFox and Chrome have some really nice graphical debugging tools which make these things easier.