# No saving or outputting is possible in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, save, output

In [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24668363/javascript-how-to-get-a-translated-word-out-of-the-field-of-a-google-translate) I just learned how to illicit one desired element out of a Google translate page. There I have also learned that placing anything into clipboard in Javascript is literately impossible (you can do it by prompting a window asking a user to save some value into the clipboard - but you can't do that automatically), which is a rather sad thing to me as I really need to save that element out of a Google translate page automatically.

I wonder if it's at least possible in Javascript to save some values in a separate file on my computer? In the [**w3schools.com tutorial on Javascript**](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_output.asp) it is stated that "*JavaScript does not have any print or output functions*". Does that mean that saving info on my computer is absolutely impossible in Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
// Assuming the text you want to save is in variable 'contentVar'
uriContent = "data:application/octet-stream," + encodeURIComponent(contentVar);
window.location.href = uriContent;
```

Your browser should then download a file that contains whatever is inside `contentVar`.

The downside of this is that you can't set the file name. Doing this in a cross-browser way is difficult, but as always, there's a library to help! [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js)

Comment: thank you very much for this code, but can you, please, tell me what will be the name of the file and what will be the path?

Comment: @brilliant Unfortunately, it fill result in a file download that is named whatever the browser wants. In firefox, it's just a bunch of random letters. I'm editing the answer to allow setting the file name.

Comment: "Doing this in a cross-browser way is difficult, but as always, there's a library to help! FileSaver.js" - I have never used libraries before, don't know how to do it. I am studying that page now. "In firefox, it's just a bunch of random letters" - It's actually okay with me as long as I know the path, but how can I know the path?

Comment: It should be saved to your default download folder. You should get a notification that a download is occurring.